# MYSQL find highest value from last n row

Tags: mysql, max

I have database with outside temperature. Rows - id, datetime and temperature, there is thousand records. How to find highest temperature from last n rows?

I´d like to find highest value from last 50 records in table, by this command:

```
SELECT DATETIME, temperature from table ORDER BY DATETIME DESC LIMIT 50;
```

this command not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max(temperature) 
from your_table 
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max(temperature) from table ORDER BY DATETIME DESC LIMIT 50;
```

or if you want date wise temperature

```
SELECT Date(DATETIME), max(temperature) from table ORDER BY DATETIME DESC LIMIT 50 group by Date(DATETIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT max(temperature) 
from table
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC 
LIMIT 50 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

i try our advice, but when i in php write:

```
echo $row['DATETIME']. $row['temperature']. "<br />" ;
```

on the page is only error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    MAX(temperature)
FROM (
    SELECT
        temperature
    FROM
        table
    ORDER BY
        id DESC
    LIMIT 50
) t
```

Sorting by id would be quicker than by DATETIME in case bigger DATETIME  always have bigger id

Comment: As long as you have an index on datetime, it should be just as fast to order by datetime as id.